# using this "kill -9 $(ps -ef | grep post)" to kill relevant Postgres progress,but it start as soon as it being killed

Tags: linux, macos, postgresql, kill

Because using "pg_ctl" to start postgresql in my macbook, it always tells me that some postmaster already occupied the 5432 port.

### (before I install pgsql from source code , I installed it from binary package.)

using "ps -ef|grep post" to check it.it has 7 progress.one is postmaster,the father progress.
Importantly,the postmaster progress is in the /Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/bin/postmaster,which doesn't exist.the folder "PostgreSQL" maybe be deleted when I uninstall the binary package Postgresql.

---

Under this background,this is my problem:
I want to stop the nonexistent postmaster progress and its child progress using "kill -9 $(ps -ef | grep post)",but it start as soon as it being killed.
what can I do to deal with it????
thank you very much if you can help me.....

Comment: You want to stop the "nonexistent postmaster progress" ?  How does that even make sense?   If you kill a process with signal 9 (SIGKILL) you do not allow the process to clean up its TCP ports.  The OS will keep the TCP ports reserved for a while before the ports become available to other programs.

Comment: Are you mean that the OS will save the port for the progress I kill for a while or ,just,save the port waiting another progress to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does postgres not use a watchdog to check if all processes are running? If not start them. I'm not sure about it but it would explain why it appears to be killed. Has the started child process a new PID?

Comment: No but Postgres keeps track of his own processes. The idea behind this is that if a child process fails for some reason, it is reforked to pickup where it dropped out. For a database this is very important as a killed process can lead to data corruption. I would seriously recommend to use the default start/stop because, like any other database, there are shutdown routines.

Comment: After read your comment,here is my understanding:Is the default start/stop ways of PostgreSQL is the "pg_ctl"? if it is ,using the pg_ctl I should have the /data (create when using "initdb") which can't be find .